# Using Vieta's Formulas to find expression involving polynomial roots

Tags: roots

I'm having trouble with this problem.

Show that if the roots of $$5x^3-x^2-2x+3=0$$ are $a_1,a_2,a_3$, then $$1/a_1+1/a_2+1/a_3=2/3$$

Comment: $1/a_1+1/a_2+1/a_3=(a_2 a_3 +a_1 a_3+a_1 a_2)/(a_1 a_2 a_3)$ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas

Comment: The [Fundamental Theorem of Algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) says something different.

Comment: I'm supposed to use FTA to solve it. I forgot to mention that.

Comment: The FTA has nothing to do with the solution of this problem. Viète's formulas are completely independent of it; if you assume the existence of the roots, you don't need to find them, do you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use that since $a_1,a_2,a_3$ are the roots of the polynomial then $$5x^3-x^2-2x+3=5(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)$$ Expand the right side and compare the coefficients of equal powers of $x$ to obtain that $$\begin{cases}a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_2a_3=-\dfrac{2}{5}\\a_1a_2a_3=-\dfrac{3}{5}\end{cases}$$ Now $$\frac{a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_2a_3}{a_1a_2a_3}=\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2}+\frac{1}{a_3}$$ gives you the result.

Comment: Any hints to show that $$a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2=21/25$$?

Comment: @user183782 Again with coefficient comparison you know that $(a_1+a_2+a_3)=1$ and therefore $(a_1+a_2+a_3)^2=1/25$ which implies that $$a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2=1/25-2(a_1a_2+a_1a_3+a_2a_3)=1/25-2(-2/5)=1/25+20/25=21/25$$ as you want.

Answer (score 13):

The equation $3y^3-2y^2-y+5=0$ has roots the reciprocals of the roots of $5x^3-x^2-2x+3=0$. To see this, divide the given polynomial through by $x^3$, and reverse the order of summation.

The sum of the roots of $ 3y^3-2y^2-y+5=0$ is $-\frac{-2}{3}$.

Comment: That's a very nice argument.

Comment: Always nice to go reciprocal!

Answer (score 5):

$$\frac{1}{a_1}+\frac{1}{a_2} + \frac{1}{a_2} = \frac{a_2a_3+a_1a_3+a_1a_2}{a_1a_2a_3} = \frac{(-2)/5}{(-1)^3 \cdot 3/5}=\frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: Reference: Vieta formulas.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas/

Comment: You might want to explain how you got values for a1, a2, and a3...rather than a link